# What does session_store.rb do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

Hi everybody
I don't understand the usefulness of the session_store.rb file, I tried to read some docs, but I still don't understand, for example, why should I edit that file?

Answer (score 3):

You can change the underlying mechanism of your Session store:

Default is using cookie_store:

```
Yourapp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_yourapp_session'
```

However, you can change it to use ActiveRecord, meaning your DB:

```
Yourapp::Application.config.session_store :active_record_store
```

Read the Session section of the following tutorial:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html